# csv file process in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I work with a csv data as follow:

```
ticker,exchange_country,company_name,price,exchange_rate,shares_outstanding,net_income
1,HK,CK HUTCHISON HOLDINGS LTD,1.404816984,7.757949829,3859.677979,31633
2,HK,CLP HOLDINGS LTD,1.312602194,7.757949829,2526.450928,16319
3,HK,HONG KONG & CHINA GAS CO LTD,0.234939214,7.757949829,12717.04199,7546.200195
11,HK,HANG SENG BANK LTD,2.198193203,7.757949829,1911.843018,15451
```

I have a StockStatRecord class:

```
class StockStatRecord:

    def __init__(self, stock_load):
        self.name = stock_load[0]
        self.company_name = stock_load[2]
        self.exchange_country = stock_load[1]
        self.price = stock_load[3]
        self.exchange_rate = stock_load[4]
        self.shares_outstanding = stock_load[5]
        self.net_income = stock_load[6]
```

How am I supposed to create another class to extract the data from that CSV, parse it, create new record and return the record created? In this class, it also needs to validate the rows when reading. Validation will fail for any row that is missing any piece of information, or if the name (symbol or player name) is empty, or if any of the numbers(int or float) cannot be parsed ( watch out of the division by zero).

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this,  either rolling out the code yourself, or using a Python module that is made for veryfing data-schemas, like [Colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/), or the extended CSV reader in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (as Zwinck posted in the comment above).

What is not usually needed is a separate class to check values-  you can do that on the same class - or usually, have a base class that implements the data-validation mechanisms, and then just have extra information on each field for the actual data classes. And finally, if you need to process data and spill an object back, there is no need for a class because in Python you can have functions independents of classes - there is no need to try to hammer down every piece of code to a class.

One simple thing to there is to (1) use Python's csv.DictReader instead of csv.Reader to read the rows - that way you have each piece of data bound to the column name already, as a dict, instead of a list where you have to manually track the column numbers, then set a `property` for each of the columns you need validation, so that the fields can be validated on setting - and a `__init__` method that simply assigns all fields to their respectiv attributes:

```
class SockStatRecord:
    def __init__(self, row):
         for key, value in row.items():
               setattr(self, key, value)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if not name:  # example verification for empty name
             raise ValueError
        self._name = name
    # continue for other fields

   import csv
   reader = csv.Dictreader(open("mydatafile.csv"))
   all_records = []
   for row in reader:
       try:
           all_records.append(StockDataRecord(row))
       except ValueError:
           print("Some error at record: {}".format(row))
```